# Java - Retrieving image from clipboard - image cropped left and right

Tags: java, image, copy, clipboard, paste

we have a feature in our application that allows us to paste files or image data as a "document". Pasting image works fine, unless the image was copied out of an HTML E-Mail in Microsoft Outlook. When doing it like that, there's one quarter of the image missing on the left and one quarter missing on the right. The image was intially 2560x1440. I don't use any magic code for retrieving the image from the clipboard.

This is the code for retrieving the `Image` object from the clipboard:

```
    final Transferable transferable = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents( null );
    if ( transferable != null && transferable.isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor.imageFlavor ) )
    {
      try
      {
        return (Image) transferable.getTransferData( DataFlavor.imageFlavor );
      }
      catch ( UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException exception )
      {
        logger.error( "Error while retrieving image from clipboard.", exception );
      }
    }

    return null;
```

At this point, the image already seems to be broken. As a naive way of confirming this, I have done the following:

```
      final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( new JLabel( new ImageIcon( getImageFromClipboard() ) ) );
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, scrollPane );
```

This will display the broken image in a `JOptionPane`. I have tested the same pasting with Microsoft Paint and Paint.net. In Microsoft Paint it works fine, but Paint.net seems to do the same mistake as Java does. Is there anything I am overseeing here? Or is my only choice to manually read the image from the clipboard instead of letting the Java standard library doing it for me?

I couldn't find any related bug entries in the java bugtracker for this.

I have experienced this using OpenJDK 8.212 and OpenJDK 12 on Windows 10.

Here is a small example that's runnable:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Main
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    final JLabel image = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( getImageFromClipboard() ) );
    final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( image );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, scrollPane );
  }

  private static Image getImageFromClipboard()
  {
    final Transferable transferable = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
        .getSystemClipboard()
        .getContents( null );
    if ( transferable != null && transferable.isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor.imageFlavor ) )
    {
      try
      {
        return (Image) transferable.getTransferData( DataFlavor.imageFlavor );
      }
      catch ( UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException exception )
      {
        exception.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

**Update**
Paint.net 4.2+ has the same issue: https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/114697-error-pasting-images-from-outlook-in-42-update/?tab=comments#comment-560425

Funnily enough with Outlook 2010. In my case the application was outlook too. So this might be an outlook bug?